# Use of softinput_mode for keyboard in kivy on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, kivymd

I am using Kivy/KivyMD (version 2.1.0 and 0.104.2 respectively) on a raspberry pi running Raspbian Gnu/Linux 10 (buster).

Is the softinput mode feature compatible with kivy on the raspberry pi?

And if so, how do I get it to work?

Setting the softinput mode via

```
Window.softinput_mode = 'pan'
```

anywhere in the code does not work. When set to 'pan', the keyboard does not show up at all.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if you have set the keyboard to 'systemandock' in the config.ini file after that you can set the keyboard softinput.